# What can be the most efficient way to remove first 10 elements from tuple?(every elements)

Tags: python

[THE PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Izh.png)

Hi, I am currently learning python and opencv. I want to get only name of the dog species from the above pic, which removing the first 10 strings and numbers after the dog species.

For example:

`[('n00000000-Maltese_dog', 252')]` to `'Maltese_dog'`.

I would appreciated if you can provide me any information of removing 'n' elements from tuple, or any help.

Thank you! Hope yall have a great day

Comment: Don't post images of code. Put the actual data (or a minimal representation of it) in the question and then format it by indenting 4 spaces.

Comment: Use string slicing.  `mytuple[0] = mytuple[0][10:]`

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of it in terms of removing items, think of extracting the data you want.

For each tuple, `t`,  in the list take the first item `t[0]` and then take a slice of the string `t[0][10:]`. You can use a list comprehension to make a new list of all the strings:

```
l = [
    ('n00000000-Maltese_dog', '252'),
    ('n10030000-Australian terrier', '252')
]

[t[0][10:] for t in l]
# ['Maltese_dog', 'Australian terrier']
```